# Wrong image colour when streaming from 16-bit depth webcam on Chrome OS

Tags: javascript, webrtc, chromium, webcam, google-chrome-os

I want to display the video stream from a USB thermal camera - for the record, it's a [FLIR Lepton PureThermal 2](https://groupgets.com/manufacturers/getlab/products/purethermal-2-flir-lepton-smart-i-o-module) - on my web app, running on a Chrome OS (version 85.0.4183.84 - latest available).

At first I assumed the device could be streamed as a standard webcam, so I came up with the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Webcam test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="videoElement" width="800" height="600" muted autoplay></video>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  let videoElement = document.getElementById('videoElement');

  if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {

    let videoDevices = [];
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
    .then(devices => {
      videoDevices = devices.filter(device => {
        if (device.kind !== "videoinput") return;
        console.debug(`Identified video input: ${JSON.stringify(device)}`);
        return true;
      });

      let selectedCamera = videoDevices[videoDevices.length - 1]; // usually the thermal camera will be the last one
      console.debug(`Streaming device ${JSON.stringify(selectedCamera)}...`);

      return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: {
          deviceId: { exact: selectedCamera.deviceId },
          width: {exact: 160 }, height: {exact: 120 }, // forcing QQVGA resolution
        },
      });
    })
    .then(stream => {
      videoElement.srcObject = stream;
      videoElement.play();
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

</script>

</html>
```

The code above works as expected on any browser on Windows 10, but I'm not getting the image I was expecting on Chrome OS. See the comparison below:
[image]

If you look closely, Chrome is in fact streaming something, it's just not clear enough. Changing the image's level and contrast gives me this:
[image]

Just for the record, the code works in all browsers below (tested on Windows 10 only):

- Chrome 85.0.4183.83
- Firefox 80.0
- Opera 70.0.3728.133
- Edge 85.0.564.41
- Edge Legacy (probably version 40)

What am I missing in my code to make it work on Chrome OS work like it does for Chrome on Windows?

Comment: Might it be a “different device” in Chrome? Does the page have video enabled? I use a webcam in Chrome for meetings routinely.. does this thermal camera differ in output somehow (does a “normal” local webcam work in the Chromium browsers)?

Comment: @user2864740 - all detected cameras are being logged on the console, so I can confirm the browser is streaming the right device. Video is definitely enabled - I tested the same code with my standard webcam and that works as expected. Perhaps the thermal camera doesn't work exactly as a webcam? Not sure why it shows the right image on Firefox though.

Comment: Maybe an unsupported (by Chromium) video profile..? If there are any technical details on the camera they might include some pertinent information.

Comment: @user2864740 The only suspicious spec I could find on the manufacturer's documentation was the webcam resolution, which is QQVGA. That actually helped me fix it for Chrome on Windows, but the problem remains on Chrome OS. I've updated my question with further details.

Comment: What if you don't pass it any constraints and let the browser choose what's best? `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})...`

Comment: @Kaiido The first version of my code was exactly like that, but sadly the grey image was all I got from the thermal camera.

Comment: if it works when you start chrome with `--disable-features=MediaFoundationVideoCapture` file a chrome bug please.

Comment: @PhilippHancke this was one of the flags that I had tested, both enabled and disabled, but the problem remained the same. In the end what fixed it on Windows was to force the video to be in a QQVGA resolution. I'll update my question to clarify that the problem has been fixed on Windows, but not on Chrome OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work on Chrome OS by doing the following:

- As soon as the video starts playing, save the bytes from the current frame into a texture buffer (with the help of WebGL)
- For every pixel in the frame, multiply the red channel by 65535, returning the temperature in centikelvin
- Convert it to celsius and manipulate the pixels to show a grey scale image within a temperature range
- Draw the pixel on a canvas
- Request a new frame (restarting the loop)

See sample code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-wood-umo9w?file=/index.html

Result: [image]

Special thanks to [Aleksandar Stojiljkovic](https://01.org/chromium/blogs/astojilj/2017/depth-camera-capture-html5) and [Kurt Kiefer](https://groups.google.com/g/flir-lepton/c/88PrZI1-A8I/m/bw0uaabJCAAJ).

The same result could be achieved by applying a custom shader to the texture instead.

I'm still not sure why Chrome OS handles the video differently, so I've raised an issue on [Chromium issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1125329) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you set 160x120, you will get a normalized image (RGB888).

If you set 160x122, you will get a black and white image (Y16), the bottom 2 pixels are useless.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tested that on different devices running Chrome OS (Chromebook, Chromebox, Chromebit, etc) and no matter what resolution I set, it's always displaying the grey-ish image like your top-left image. Given that you're running your sample from the D drive, I don't think that's a Chrome OS, right?